# Two-dimensional lookup in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm doing a 2-dimensional lookup in Google Sheets to find a name anywhere on the sheet and return the value in the fourth column of the same row that the name appears in. The name may appear in multiple locations, and I want to display results for each instance, so this will need to output as an array.

Below is what I currently have; is there a more elegant way to do this?

I'd like to avoid using Apps Script for this if possible (another user asked a similar question and that was the suggestion).

```
=iferror(if(E3 = "", "", index(unique(query('TransposedT&O'!$A$1:$BB$70, "select D where
E contains '" & E3 & "' or
F contains '" & E3 & "' or
G contains '" & E3 & "' or
H contains '" & E3 & "' or
I contains '" & E3 & "' or
J contains '" & E3 & "' or
K contains '" & E3 & "' or
L contains '" & E3 & "' or
M contains '" & E3 & "' or
N contains '" & E3 & "' or
O contains '" & E3 & "' or
P contains '" & E3 & "' or
Q contains '" & E3 & "' or
R contains '" & E3 & "' or
S contains '" & E3 & "' or
T contains '" & E3 & "' or
U contains '" & E3 & "' or
V contains '" & E3 & "' or
Q contains '" & E3 & "' or
R contains '" & E3 & "' or
S contains '" & E3 & "' or
T contains '" & E3 & "' or
U contains '" & E3 & "' or
V contains '" & E3 & "' or
W contains '" & E3 & "' or
X contains '" & E3 & "' or
Y contains '" & E3 & "' or
Z contains '" & E3 & "' or
AA contains '" & E3 & "' or
AB contains '" & E3 & "' or
AC contains '" & E3 & "' or
AD contains '" & E3 & "' or
AE contains '" & E3 & "' or
AF contains '" & E3 & "' or
AG contains '" & E3 & "' or
AH contains '" & E3 & "' or
AI contains '" & E3 & "' or
AJ contains '" & E3 & "' or
AK contains '" & E3 & "' or
AL contains '" & E3 & "' or
AM contains '" & E3 & "' or
AN contains '" & E3 & "' or
AO contains '" & E3 & "' or
AP contains '" & E3 & "' or
AQ contains '" & E3 & "' or
AR contains '" & E3 & "' or
AS contains '" & E3 & "' or
AT contains '" & E3 & "' or
AU contains '" & E3 & "' or
AV contains '" & E3 & "' or
AQ contains '" & E3 & "' or
AR contains '" & E3 & "' or
AS contains '" & E3 & "' or
AT contains '" & E3 & "' or
AV contains '" & E3 & "' or
AW contains '" & E3 & "' or
AX contains '" & E3 & "' or
AY contains '" & E3 & "' or
AZ contains '" & E3 & "' or
BA contains '" & E3 & "' or
BB contains '" & E3 & "'"
, 0)), 1, 1)), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(E3="",, INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY({'TransposedT&O'!$A$1:$BB$70}, 
 "select Col4 where "&TEXTJOIN(" or ", 1, "Col"&TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(E:BB))&
 " contains '"&E3&"'"), 0)), 1, 1)), ))
```

Comment: ...maybe it could be shorter if you would share a copy of your sheet...

Comment: It works! I'll need to spend a bit of time breaking this apart to fully understand each part, but for now it works like a charm. Thanks!